# How can I replace "map-09" by `map-09` in R? (from double quotes to single quotes)

Tags: r, quotes

I tried with `gsub`, and `str_replace`, but I didn't get what I need.

```
gsub("\"", "\`", "map-09", fixed=TRUE)
```

gives `"map-09"` and not `map-09`

```
str_replace("map-09","\"","\`")
```

gives `"map-09"` and not `map-09`

Comment: You may need `paste` or `sQuote("map-09", FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused between the way the string is being represented vs. what the string actually is. The functions you're using don't actually add any quotes. But when the output is printed quotes are there to show you that it is a string being represented. If you use the function 'cat' to print the output you'll see it without the quotes.

See the difference between

```
print("example")
cat("example")
```

Comment: Thank you!  Now my code is working!  I was needing "cat".  First I was trying leaflet(paste("mapa_chile","Valparaíso","2020-04-10",sep="-")) but I added cat and to it and now is working:   leaflet(cat(paste("mapa_chile","Valparaíso","2020-04-10",sep="-")))